# Running groupByKey/ reduceBuKey on partitioned data, but with different key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an ordered RDD of type `((id, ts), some value)`. This was partitioned using a custom partitioner on the `id` field only.

```
math.abs(id.hashCode % numPartitions)
```

Now If I run the following two functions on this partitioned RDD, will it involve shuffling and re-partitioning of the dataset.

```
val partitionedRDD: ((id:Long, ts:Long), val:String) = <Some Function>
val flatRDD = orderedRDD.map(_ => (_._1.id, (_._1.ts, _._2)))
```

What I want to know is, whether `flatRDD.groupByKey()` and `flatRDD.reduceByKey()` will have the same partitioning as the partitionedRDD or Spark will shuffle the dataset again and create new partitions?

Thanks,
Devi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, performing `groupByKey` or `reduceByKey` on `flatRDD` will necessarily cause another shuffle.

Since you know your `flatRDD` is already partitioned by `id`, you can safely assume that all records with the same `id` reside within a single partition. Therefore, if you want to `groupBy(id)`, you can use `mapPartitions` (with `preservesPartitioning = true`) and perform that operation on each partition separately, thus preventing Spark from shuffling your data:

```
flatRDD.mapPartitions({ it =>
  it.toList
    .groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.size) // some grouping + reducing the result
    .iterator

}, preservesPartitioning = true)
```

This will not cause an extra shuffle:

[image]